# How to apply a margin to these absolutely positioned <a> elements?

Tags: html, css

**[JSFiddle here!](https://jsfiddle.net/r6a4nn55/)**

In the following SSCCE (screenshot of output follows), I want the `<a>` elements to have a kinda `margin` of `10px` between then, such that they are about `10px` apart from each other. But they have a `position:absolute` (it is a requirement in my real code, I can't change it), so they overlap each other when I give them a `margin`.

**What should I do to set them `10px` apart from each other, such that they also appear to be center aligned on the horizontal axis of the page** - they are already in they `center` because of `margin:0px auto`; on `.wrapper`, just don't disrupt that!

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.anchor1 {
  left: 0px;
}
.anchor2 {
  left: 25%;
}
.anchor3 {
  left: 50%;
}
.wrapper .anchor::before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  content: " ";
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.anchor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25vw;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-height: 190px;
  top: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.span-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}
.span-one {
  font-size: 271.579%;
  color: #FFF;
}
.span-two {
  font-size: 214.737%;
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="anchor anchor1" href="#" style="left:0; width:33.333333333333%; background-image: url('http://shutupandtakemethere.com/pics/022014/stairs-in-a-japanese-garden-big.jpg');"></a>
  <a class="anchor anchor2" href="#" style="left:33.333333333333%; width:33.333333333333%; background-image: url('http://piximus.net/media/9366/beautiful-places-on-the-world-20.jpg');"></a>
  <a class="anchor anchor3" href="#" style="left: 66.666666666667%; width:33.333333333333%; background-image:url('http://freetopwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/free-beautiful-place-wallpaper-hd-161.jpg')"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: why not reduce the width ?

Comment: @ElheniMokhles Actually I used to hard-coded width here only, actually the width is being dynamically being created by doing something like "divide 100 by the number-of-anchor-tags", e.g. here there are 3 anchor tags, so "100/3=33.333333333333", so the width is "width:33.333333333333%". Secondly I don't think reducing the width will solve the problem at all.

Comment: @Solace if you reduced your width, it would solve your issue, try changing the width to 32.3333333% in your fiddle and see the difference. If it's programatically created, try taking 10px away from the width before applying it.

Comment: Why do you have to use absolute position? it looks like can be done easily with inline-block or table-cell or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `calc` property of CSS,
Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r6a4nn55/1/

Just give a width like this,

```
width: calc(33.333333333333% - 20px);
```

The browser support is good. On desktop the concerns would be it's IE 9+, Safari 6+, and won't be in Opera until it is on Blink in 15+. On mobile, Android and Opera Mini don't support it at all yet and iOS just on 6.0+.

So I recommend you to use a fallback width value like this,

```
.anchor {
    position: absolute;
    height: 25vw;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 190px;
    top: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 33%; /*fallback value if browser not supported calc*/
    width: calc(33.333333333333% - 20px); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this solution the margin between the Anchors arnt exactly 10 px but there is a space between and if you dont need to be responsive you could go qith px values.

All i did was to remove the inline styles and put them in the anchor css styles with a reduced with and a bit more left. ;)

```css
.wrapper {
 width:100%;
 max-width:90%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 
 position:relative;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
}


.anchor1 {
 left:0px;
    width:25%;
    background-image:url('http://shutupandtakemethere.com/pics/022014/stairs-in-a-japanese-garden-big.jpg');
}

.anchor2 {
 left:30%;
    width:25%;
    background-image: url('http://piximus.net/media/9366/beautiful-places-on-the-world-20.jpg');
    
}

.anchor3 {
 left:60%;
    width:25%;
    background-image:url('http://freetopwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/free-beautiful-place-wallpaper-hd-161.jpg');
}

.wrapper .anchor::before {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 content: " ";
 transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.anchor {
 position: absolute;
    height: 25vw;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 190px;
    top: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.span-container {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 left: 10%;
 bottom: 10%;
 width: 80%;
}

.span-one {
 font-size: 271.579%;
 color: #FFF;
}

.span-two {
 font-size: 214.737%;
 display: block;
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: 100;
 line-height: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="anchor anchor1" href="#"></a>
    <a class="anchor anchor2" href="#"></a>
    <a class="anchor anchor3" href="#"></a>
</div>
```